# java boolean array and turning every third value to false

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

The Boolean array is initialized to true. I need to know how to turn every third value to false and also going through the array over and over. It is essentially duck duck goose without the randomness.

Comment: How will you know when to stop iterating?

Comment: By over and over I meant one the array gets to the end I need it to go back to position zero and skip over the false values.

Comment: So you finish when there are no TRUE value left?

Comment: There needs to be one True left.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a beginners programming exercise, so I'm going to just give you a hint or two:

- Go back to your textbook, lecture notes, tutorial and reread the stuff on `for` loops.  Focus on the old style ones.
- Think about how to write a for loop that steps through integer index values in the pattern that you require.
- Re *"... going through the array over and over"* - not sure what you mean, but maybe the hint for this is to think about using nested loops; i.e. a loop inside another loop.

But the most important advice is to try and work this out for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm really not sure what you mean by going through the array over and over but the following code will turn every third value to false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVar.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        myVar[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Edit: Oops someone beat me to it while I was typing lol.

Comment: By over and over I meant one the array gets to the end I need it to go back to position zero and skip over the false values. Thanks for the help.